# How to properly update Three20?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, three20

I've just update my version of Xcode to 4.2 - Xcode has given me a load of warnings from the Three20 source. - So I guess the version of Three20 I have must not be compatible with iOS 5?

I'm using the recommended shared directory layout but have manually downloaded the files from the zip, not using git.

Once I have re-downloaded the files into the shared directory, should I do anything else to update my project - run the Three20 python script?

Comment: Not an answer to your question (hence a comment...).... We have just adopted a project that uses Three20. Its complete crap. It will give you quick results now - but its a maintenance nightmare trying to change anything. Undocumented bloatware. I don't like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master branch in three20 is a little outdated. All the complier warning in three20 have been fixed in the latest development branch.

You can download the latest development version from: https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/development